# Background image show in Firefox but not in IE, might be z-index issue

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox, z-index

I create a site and it work on Firefox but not in IE, the background image is gone actually seem like the div is gone, might also be a z-index problem, could you please help :(

the following is HTML code

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Home -->
    <div id="landing" class="panel">
        <img src="images/bgmain_no_producer.jpg" class="bg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

the following is CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 90 % ;
    /*float:left;*/
    min - height: 100 % ;
    height: auto!important;
    height: 100 % ;
    margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
}
.panel {
    min - width: 100 % ;
    height: 100 % ;
    overflow - y: hidden;
    overflow - x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin - top: -150 % ;
    margin - left: -5 % ;
    background - color: #555555;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
}

img.bg {
/* Set rules to fill background */
    min-width: 250px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50%;   /* 50% */
    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
/* Set up positioning */
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index:-999;
}
```

Comment: why `z-index: -999` ?? this could be the problem. Did you try giving `z-index: 1` or some positive values?

Comment: put width and height in IMG tag, you have not specified any fixed height in the CSS, auto or % does not make any sense to IE

Comment: margin-top: -150%; on the panel deoesn't seem right without any top value to bring it back on screen. Can you tell us what your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The image is not visible because of `opacity: 0` (makes the element invisible) and `margin-top: -150%;` to your `.panel` class. remove them it will work.

---

As specified in [**W3C**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties), the `margin` properties including `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` refers the **width** of the containing block (not the *height*), if set in `percentages`.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f57q6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Also if the intention was to have the image fade in, then you need to change the opacity to 1 after the document has loaded.

```
document.getElementById('landing').style.opacity = 1;
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcJ2a/)